# Where can I find Adobe AIR on my PC?

Tags: air

I want to open an AIR application with the AIR which was presumably installed with CS5, but not knowing what it's called I can't find its location. So, question: what is the runtime called under Windows and/or in which folder should I be able to find it?
TIA
Steven

Note: double-clicking it doesn't help, as Flash Player tries to open it then.

**Edit**
I seem to be a bit confused here. I thought I could install to AIR from a `.SWF` files, but it looks like I have to go the way of the **publish** function in Flash. Sorry for the confusion (yes, I'm new to this :-))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Air's application installer is located at:

32bit:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe AIR\Versions\1.0\Adobe AIR Application Installer.exe
```

64bit:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe AIR\Versions\1.0\Adobe AIR Application Installer.exe
```

If you want to run your air app via command line, you can use the `Air Debug Launcher`: http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2008/11/how_to_launch_an_air_app_from_the_command_line.html

Comment: Accepted as answer because it answers my original question (though I was wrong about AIR's workflow)

Comment: The link you shared is now broken :(

Answer (score 0):

You should install the AIR runtime again, if double clicking a **.AIR** file doesn't start the install/reinstall cycle for that App, the AIR runtime / framework isn't properly installed.

- Go get the installer : http://get.adobe.com/air/

### Update:

@stevenvh : **.SWF** files are not run by the AIR Runtime, and can only be run from the regular FlashPlayer (or from within another running SWF or AIR application.)

**AIR Runtime** is for installing and running specifically built AIR application packages on the desktop.